# How to make your if shorter?

Tags: c#

I understood that when using Regex I can enter the value `|` to search for many values. For example:

```
Regex sabrina = new Regex("Rihanna|rihanna|Sabrina|sabrina");
```

I have a string which I want to compare to other values, so I use `if` like this:

```
if (rihanna == "Rihanna" || rihanna == "sabrina")
```

My question is if it possible to make the `if` shorter? I know this code is not working but what I'm looking for something like this:

```
if (rihanna == "Rihanna|sabrina")
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why does shorter matter here?

Comment: `Regex sabrina =` I knew it! Regexes are female! That must be why so many people don't understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for easier maintenance of a potentially long list of string candidates, why not use a switch statement? Technically it will be "longer" character-wise, but if you have to modify things down the road, or provide some subtle secondary processing, it could make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 5):

Single line solution:

```
if("Rihanna|rihanna|Sabrina|sabrina".Split(new[] {'|'}).Contains(rihanna))
```

or without `String.Split` method usage:

```
if ((new[] { "Rihanna", "rihanna", "Sabrina", "sabrina" }).Contains(rihanna))
```

If that kind of check is performed more than once you should save `string[]` array of possible values into a variable:

```
var names = new[] { "Rihanna", "rihanna", "Sabrina", "sabrina" };

if(names.Contains(rihanna))
```

Comment: I think that last option looks like the best bet in the long run. Easy to maintain if more options are needed, you could even pass an existing collection in if you're looking for some additional dynamic processing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `List<string>` along with the [`Enumerable.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) method.

Example:

```
var values = new List<string> { "Rihanna", "rihanna", "Sabrina", "sabrina" };

if (values.Contains(rihanna)) 
{
    // etc.
}
```

The `if` statement is now a lot more concise, and you can add more items to your list quickly and easily. If you're performing this operation frequently, you should move the declaration of the list to a member variable in the containing class so that you don't incur the overhead of list initialization every time this method is called.

An even better solution would be to use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) and [`String.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals.aspx) to perform a case-insensitive comparison:

```
if (values.Any(x => String.Equals(rihanna, x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   // your code here
}
```

Although the `if` statement is now longer, the solution is much more robust.

Comment: In the end, he'll have to create the `List<string>` so it will actually be longer

Comment: @caerolus - the code might be longer, but the **if** will be shorter.

Comment: The question is answered but I don't see the benefit in trying to make it shorter at the expense of more code elsewhere. Why do you need to shorten it?

Comment: @StevenMarciano That's a great question. The second version of my code is longer, but handles a lot more cases (no pun intended) -- much better than a shorter, less useful piece of code.

Comment: @Donut I commented just before I saw your edit. I like your second solution - very nice

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above answers, perhaps you could consider using an extension method:

```
public static bool EqualsAny(this string input, params string[] values)
{
    return values.Any(v => String.Equals(input, v, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

With usage like:

```
if (rihanna.EqualsAny("Rihanna", "Sabrina"))
```

This should give pretty readable/compact/short `if` comparisons for you, especially in comparison to some of the other alternatives here.

Tweak the `EqualsAny` check if you want to have the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` or not or feel free to add any overloads you wish. Could even implement the whole piping/splitting where you'd pass in "Rihanna|Sabrina".

EDIT: Perhaps more critically, it centralizes *how* you compare rather than duplicating the code everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own Regex and use it as a single line..

```
if (Regex.Match(rihanna, "Rihanna|rihanna|Sabrina|sabrina").Success)
```

Or make it case-insensative like this..

```
if (Regex.Match(rihanna, "rihanna|sabrina", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success){
```

Comment: To ignore the case of the first letter only, one could also use `[Rr]ihanna|[Ss]abrina`

Answer (score 0):

Ignore casing, which looks like something you're going for, and use `String.Compare`:

```
if(String.Compare(rihanna, "sabrina", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 ||
   String.Compare(rihanna, "rihana", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) or [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503873.aspx) (potentially with case insensitive check on names) is another approach which will give you better performance if you have more than several items and repeat checks often.

```
 var listToCheck = new Dictionary<string, string>( 
     StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) { { "rihanna", null}};

 if (listToCheck.ContainsKey("Rihanna")) ....
```